# XTerm and other Xwindows Terminal not open prompt, how to correct the problem?

Tags: bash, xorg, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to open an xterm-type terminal or even the standard "Terminal" in xwindows, I use Gnome on a Linux Ubuntu 18 on an Acer Aspire 5610 (32bits) and I don't know what happened. The window opens just keeps the cursor flashing.

[image]

I checked the `/etc/shells` file and everything is correct, I normally enter the shell when I choose `[ctrl] + [f3]` or another command line sequence without XWindows without problems.

Someone, would you recommend a revision so that xterm and Xwindow's "Terminal" reopen the Shell, I use BASH by default.

Comment: When you log in via Ctrl-Alt-F3 you will get a *login shell*. Normally, GUI terminal emulators use an *interactive, non-login* shell. The sequence of initialization files is different in the two cases - it's possible you have something in the non-login shell initialization that is causing an infinite loop (such as sourcing a file - maybe indirectly - from itself).

Comment: by text mode the login is normal, but a script is run that checks if linux is up to date, I will see the user scripts, there may be something, although I don't remember anything that can be so complex for xwindows.

Comment: doing a review of .bashrc and .profile, I identified that they call each other, strangely when the login is done via text mode there are no problems, however via xwindows goes in loop, I removed the call from the .bashrc script, because this call is wrong .

Answer (score 0):

I did a review of the `.bashrc` and `.profile` script, identified that they call each other, strangely when the login is done via text mode there are no problems, however via xwindows goes in loop, I removed the call from the `.bashrc` script, because this call it is wrong.